# Vuforia markerless device tracking not working in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, accelerometer, vuforia, gyroscope

I'm following this tutorial for unity https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-ar-games-on-unity-using-vuforia-part-1--cms-27210 but I have not luck making it, it is supposed when the camera move the cube has to stay in his position in the world, but the only thing I getting is the cube fixed in the camera.

I noticed in the logs that the device tracker is not starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix that worked for me is:
- The phone that you are using has to have a gyro. You can check it here: http://www.gsmarena.com
- The cube doesn't has to be inside the ARCamera component
- Enable device_tracking in world center mode
- In the vuforia configuration make sure that "enable device poses" and "enable prediction" is enabled
That's it!!